# C# Compiler thinks my property is a method

Tags: c#, properties

I am very new to C# and I don't understand what is wrong.  I am trying to assign a 'Name' property to my class, and then invoke it, but the compiler says "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object.'" It should be clear that "Name" is not a method but a property!

```
C#
namespace Learn_To_Code
{
    public class Elementary_Flow
    {
        // fields:
        TreeView myTreeView;
        // ....

        public Elementary_Flow()
        {
            // construct..
        }

        public string Name
        { 
            get { return myTreeView.Name; }
            set { myTreeView.Name = value; }
        }
        // more code...
    }
    class Learn_To_Code
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Elementary_Flow MyFlow = new Elementary_Flow();
            // following line throws error:
            Console.WriteLine("New Elementary Flow Created. Name: {0}", MyFlow.Name );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a semicolon to the end of the `Console.WriteLine()` line.

Comment: Do you have a method inside the Elemetary_Flow class which name is "Name"?

Comment: I pasted this into VS2010 and it compiles and runs (once I added a small `TreeView` class with a single `Name` property of type `string` - I did not use a "regular" `TreeView` object). I do get a `NullReferenceException` because myTreeView is uninitialized, but not the error you're getting. If there was a method named `Name` in `Elementary_Flow`, there would be different errors.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are missing a semicolon at the end of the `Console.Writeline` statement. Add one.

```
Console.WriteLine("New Elementary Flow Created. Name: {0}", MyFlow.Name );
```

*EDIT*

As Steve suggested in the comments, you may want to `clean` then do another `build`.

Comment: it would give "; expected error", but not the "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object.'".

Answer (score 0):

The problem must have lived somewhere other than in the code- I created a new project and copy-pasted the old project into the new project one chunk at a time, and now the new project == the old project but the error does not occur.

sorry for wasting bits.

Comment: You might have been able to solve it by performing a clean, followed by a build.